# Is there a way to change the style or behaviour of the the Google Places Autocomplete Widget?

Tags: android, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

As the Google place picker is being deprecated, I am creating a custom place picker using the Google places API.

I want to have a map with a autocomplete search box at the top of the map (basically exactly like google maps).  I know I can create my own custom layout with an autocomplete text view, but I want to know if there is a way to use the new AutocompleteSupportFragment widget instead.

I have implemented AutocompleteSupportFragment and it works fine, but I am having trouble with it's behaviour and style.

The widget creates a button at the top of the screen (that looks like a searchbar), then if you click on the button a search widget animates by sliding from the bottom of the screen.

What I want is either of the following:
1)  The search widget that slides up is already on the screen when the activity is opened. (so no sliding, you should be able to just click the searchbar and start typing).  This means there will also be no button on the screen.

2)  The search widget appears right on top of the button. (no sliding, just a change of animation so that the widget "appears" or fades in or something on top of the button)

Here is my Layout for the Map + Autocomplete screen:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    map:mapType="normal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_appbar_view" 
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.LocationPicker.LocationPickerActivity">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"



 android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteS upportFragment" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
```